# Matching Object with 2 arrays with same key but different values from JSON API and compare to state values and return that Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been trying for days to figure out the best approach and also how to make it work. I'm building a product page and each variation options is built dynamically (size, color) based on the GraphQL response it gets back. I'm used to simpler array checking but this one has me baffled and at a lost for even where to start.

So when a user clicks on "M" and "Red" it takes those values and stores them into state

```js
// State Setup

const [variations, setVariations] = useState({});

// Set Variations State that was selected
function productVariationsHandler(event) {
  setVariations({ ...variations, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
}
```

```json
// State Object after user has made their selections

{
  "variations": {
    "color": "Red",
    "size": "XL"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to take those user selected state variables ("Red", "XL") and match them to the GraphQL response in the variations object to get the `databaseId` and `regularPrice`

```json
// GraphQL Response

{
  "variations": {
    "nodes": [
      {
        "attributes": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "attributeId": 237,
              "name": "pa_color",
              "value": "True Royal"
            },
            {
              "attributeId": 220,
              "name": "pa_size",
              "value": "S"
            }
          ]
        },
        "databaseId": 1846,
        "regularPrice": "$24.95",
        "salePrice": null,
        "status": "publish"
      },
      {
        "attributes": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "attributeId": 237,
              "name": "pa_color",
              "value": "Red"
            },
            {
              "attributeId": 221,
              "name": "pa_size",
              "value": "XL"
            }
          ]
        },
        "databaseId": 1847,
        "regularPrice": "$24.95",
        "salePrice": null,
        "status": "publish"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I've tried using the `find` method and as well as `map` and even tried `for` as seen below but without avail

```js
// My Failed Attempt

// Find the Variation based on user selected options
  function findVariationProduct() {
    for (const key in variations) {
      product.variations.nodes.map((variation) => {
        const variationProduct = variation.attributes.nodes.find(
          ({ value, name }) => {
            if (name == `pa_${key}` && value == variations[key]) {
              console.log(variationProduct);
            }
          }
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For starters, you're trying to log `variationProduct` before it has been initialized. Change `console.log(variationProduct)` to `console.log(key)`

Comment: Thanks for taking a try lux. I believe key will only return the state values as it’s a for loop on variations which is the object that holds the state of what options the user has selected.

Comment: What I'm saying is this code is invalid. You are trying to access a variable that does not exist yet, resulting in a runtime error.